# Empty return from Entry (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I've written a code, which saves the background color of the window in the file, and after closing and running the program again it remembers the window colour (it saves in the file called 'data.txt').

```
# import modules

from tkinter import*  
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
import os.path

# create a window 
w=Tk()
w.title('My Application')
w.resizable(0,0)
w.geometry('300x300')


# Read files

if not(os.path.exists('data.txt')):       #check is the file exists
    print('file does not exists')
    file = open("data.txt",'w')
    file.close()

file = open("data.txt",'r')  #open a file


filelen=len(file.read())
print(len(file.read()))             #length of the file
file.close()


file = open("data.txt",'a')

print('file length is', filelen)
if filelen==0:               #if the file if empty, write default values
    file.write('0 \n0 \n0')            
    print('written to file')
file.close()

file = open("data.txt", 'r')


a=(file.readlines())


e1=float(a[0].replace(' \n',' '))
e2=float(a[1].replace(' \n',' '))    # remove '\n'
e3=float(a[2].replace(' \n',' '))


entry1=Entry()
entry2=Entry()
entry3=Entry()

def _from_rgb(rgb):
    """translates an rgb tuple of int to a tkinter friendly color code
    """
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % rgb   


file.close()

w.configure(background=_from_rgb((int(e1), int(e2), int(e3))))   #change the bg color to values from the file


def show_settings():

    settings=Tk()
    settings.geometry('400x200')

    entry1=Entry(settings)
    entry2=Entry(settings)
    entry3=Entry(settings)

    entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    entry2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    entry3.grid(row=3, column=1)

    changeInfo1=Label(settings,text='Red:',padx=20).grid(row=1, column=0)
    changeInfo2=Label(settings,text='Green:',padx=20).grid(row=2, column=0)
    changeInfo3=Label(settings,text='Blue',padx=20).grid(row=3, column=0)

    entry1.insert(1,e1)
    entry2.insert(1,e2)
    entry3.insert(1,e3)

    print(entry1.get())

    save=Button(settings,text='SAVE!',command=settings_save)
    save.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2)


def settings_save():                     #save values to a file
    file = open("data.txt",'a')
    file.write('\n' + str(entry1.get()) + ' \n' + str(entry2.get()) + '\n' + str(entry3.get()))
    file.close()


button=Button(w,text='Settings', command=show_settings).pack()
w.mainloop()
```

When i run it, it works, but when i click 'SAVE!' button in settings window, the file contents don't change. Could you pelease eplain, how can I fix it?

Comment: You's saving the `global entry1=Entry()` but input into a `local entry1=Entry()`. Read about [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to make entries global, using

```
 global entry1
```